# I cant' access my virtual machine files on azure portal

Tags: magento2, azure-virtual-machine

I have set up a Virtual Machine on Windows Azure and deployed my Magento.

I want to access files in the server, I used RDP but it gives me a connection error.

How to solve that?

Comment: Have you tried this ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/troubleshoot-rdp-connection

Comment: it worked but the problem when i try to send file or foldes to /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs it show permission denied. how i can change permission ; i'm using putty and filezilla sftp

Comment: May I know the VM OS type? In your post, it is windows, but the path you used is kind of linux. Could you please share more details of screenshots?